# Swift Compiler Error: The enum case has a single tuple as an associated value, but there are several patterns here

Tags: swift

Building a project in Xcode 11.4 beta 3, I'm getting this Swift Compiler error on an enum:

> The enum case has a single tuple as an associated value, but there are several patterns here, implicitly tupling the patterns and trying to match that instead

Source code:

```
switch result {
case .error(let err):
    //
case .value(let staff, let locations):  // <-- error on this line
    //
}
```

`Result` is an generic enum with associated values for `.error` and `.value`. In this case, the associated value is a tupple.

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case value(T)
    case error(Error)
}
```

Don't recall seeing this error before, and searching for it did not yield any results. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for leaving that out

Comment: My bad, I meant Xcode 11.4 beta 3. In regards to `Result`, I agree, it’s old code that predates `Swift.Result`. That has nothing to do with the issue, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Seems like `enum` with associated values, where the value type is a tuple, can no longer be matched on a `switch` statement like that:

```
// Works on Xcode 11.3.1, yields error on 11.4 (Swift 5.2)
switch result {
case .error(let err):
    //
case .value(let staff, let locations):  
    //
}
```

#### Solution

Values from tuple have to be manually extracted in Xcode 11.4 (Swift 5.2):

```
// Works on Xcode 11.4
switch result {
case .error(let err):
    //
case .value(let tuple):  
    let (staff, locations) = tuple
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I found you can also silence this error by treating the associated value more like a tuple by wrapping it in an extra set of brackets:

```
switch result {
case .error(let err):
    //
case .value((let staff, let locations)):  
    //
}
```

Comment: Consider moving the `let` out if you're going to bind everything, though: `case let .value( (staff, locations) ):` and `case .value( let (staff, locations) ):` both compile. Choose your fave!

Comment: Super minor but I stylistically disagree with the above comment about binding everything with a single let. Having the let just to the left of the thing being bound is easier to read and quickly understand what things are bound. Otherwise you need to mentally extrapolate what the let is binding. Google's coding guidelines for swift also advise against the single cascading let: https://google.github.io/swift/#pattern-matching

Comment: "Google's" guidelines :/

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes

> Code that relies on the compiler automatically tupling a pattern may lead to a compiler error when upgrading to Xcode 11.4, even though the code compiled before. (58425942)

For example, leaving out parentheses when switching on an Optional of a tuple type causes a compiler error:

```
switch x { // error: switch must be exhaustive
case .some((let a, let b), let c): // warning: the enum case has a
     // single tuple as an associated value, but there are several
     // patterns here, implicitly tupling the patterns and trying
     // to match that instead
...
```

}

**Workaround**: Add extra parentheses to explicitly tuple the pattern:

```
switch x {
case .some(((let a, let b), let c)): // Notice the extra pair of parentheses.
...
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, and link to the release notes. I missed that.

Comment: It's not an "issue". It's an improvement in the language. What was happening _before_ was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 12 / Swift 5.3, the warning message is greatly improved:

> Enum case 'value' has one associated value that is a tuple of 2 elements. Replace `(let staff, let locations)` with `((let staff, let locations))`.

That's far clearer. It tells you what to do, and offers to do it, as a Fix-It. Of course the alternative is to say `(let tuple)` and pass the tuple into the case's code and deal with it there, but there seems no need to say that explicitly in the warning.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, I'd like to add an answer for the `if case` version too.

```
if case let .value(staff, error) = result {
    // Do something
}
```

and then of course ignoring case:

```
if case let .value(staff, _) = result {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.3**

A clean way using **typealias** because may you have a lot of value in tuple so **typealias** make the switch case more cleaner

```
public typealias StaffLocationsData = (let staff, let locations)

switch result {
case .error(let err):
    //
case .value(let data):  
    let staffLocationsData: StaffLocationsData = data
    print(staffLocationsData.staff)
    print(staffLocationsData.locations)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead check the type and get the value in a tuple, you check the value of the condition. This is my example

```
switch result {
case let .error(err):
// Do something
case let .value(staff, locations):  // <-- error on this line
// Do something
}
```